# Errors ERROR:root:Algorithm vtkIntersectionPolyDataFilter returned failure for request, WARN| vtkDelaunay2D : Edge not recovered, polygon fill suspect

Tags: pycharm, vtk

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pyvista
import pyvista as pv
import trimesh
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('PyCharm')


mesh_1 = pv.read("E:\\škola\\Diplomka\\snimky\\kadaver\\mandibula_zjednodusena sit2.ply")
mesh_2 = pv.read("E:\škola\Diplomka\snimky\kadaver\LEBKA_zjednodusena sit3.ply")
# cpos = mesh.plot()

mesh_1.points /= 1.0

for y in range(-106, -16, 1):
    for a in range(59, 65, 1):
        for z in range(-169, -166, 1):
            with open("intersekce2.txt", "a") as f:

            mesh = mesh_1.rotate_x(a, point=(54, y, z), inplace=False)
            s1 = mesh
            s2 = mesh_2
            intersection, s1_split, s2_split = s1.intersection(s2)


            f.write("Úhel={0}, x=54, y={1}, z={2}, intersection={3} \n".format(a, y, z, intersection.n_points))
            f.close()  # Průběžné uložení změn do souboru
```

And at some points in the loop I get these errors:
ERROR:root:Algorithm vtkIntersectionPolyDataFilter (0000020FF5129BB0) returned failure for request: vtkInformation (0000020FF533B560)
2023-05-27 23:48:01.091 (  17.502s) [                ]      vtkDelaunay2D.cxx:1419  WARN| vtkDelaunay2D (0000020FF3763940): Edge not recovered, polygon fill suspect

When I enter the point in the code without the loop (below), it calculates. I can't figure out a way to clean this up. Can you think of anything? I've tried looking for different ways to solve this, but apart from upgrading the vtk library I haven't found anything.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyvista as pv
from pyvista import examples
import numpy as np
import pyvista


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('PyCharm')

mesh_1 = pv.read("F:\škola\Diplomka\snimky\kadaver\mandibula_zjednodusena sit.ply")
mesh_2 = pv.read("F:\škola\Diplomka\snimky\kadaver\LEBKA_zjednodusena sit.ply")

mesh_1.points /= 1.0

outline = mesh_1.outline()

grid = pv.UniformGrid(
        dimensions=(1, 91, 81),
         spacing=(1, 1, 1),
         origin=(54, -106.5, -246.8),)


points = grid.points
values = grid.points[0, :]
mask = points[3, 0] == 0

mesh= mesh_1.rotate_x(50, point=(54.0, -106.0, -169.0), inplace=False)

point = np.array([54.0, -94.0, -168.0])
poly = pyvista.lines_from_points(point)

s1 = mesh
s2 = mesh_2
intersection, s1_split, s2_split = s1.intersection(s2)
pl = pv.Plotter()
_ = pl.add_mesh(s1, style='wireframe') #wireframe/surface
_ = pl.add_mesh(s2, style='surface')
_ = pl.add_mesh(intersection, color='r', line_width=10)
pl.show()
```

If someone else could think of a way to incorporate a failure dump into the code after the calc takes too long, that would be the best. I'm thinking something along the lines of.

```
 if elapsed_time >= 300:
                f.write("VÝPOČET SELHAL: Úhel={0}, x=54, y={1}, z={2} \n".format(a, y, z))
                f.flush() 
                continue
```